# Did Stack Overflow do this on purpose?

Tags: bug

Might be one of the silliest things that caught my attention, but https://stackoverflow.com/about might still need a change.

[image: Q&A]

Comment: The picked question was merged with an older question. Yes, that answer *is* really older than the question.

Comment: Woah. Thanks. :D. Can't believe this was already asked.